# Getting values from energy meter to Schneider PLC

Tags: plc, structured-text

I am trying to read the values from an energy meter, and convert them to REAL (32bit float).
In this case I am reading phase 1 voltage.
Each value is read across two registers.
So I have received to WORDS of values **17268** (MSW) and **2456** (LSW) converted them into a DWORD, and then to a REAL value after multiplying by 0.1, but I am not getting the answer I'm expecting.
I should be getting **245.0375** volts.
However I am getting 1.13E+08
Please see snip of structured text with live values.
[snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PE8Z.png)

Comment: Please copy paste actual text instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `DWORD_TO_REAL` is trying to do a type conversion; that is, make the value of a `DWORD` match the format of a `REAL`. In your case, the contents of `MSW` and `LSW` are simply a IEEE754 value split in half and just need to be forced into the corresponding bits of a `REAL` variable. With TwinCAT (Beckhoff) I would do a direct memory copy:

```
MEMCPY(ADR(realValue)+2, ADR(MSW), 2);
MEMCPY(ADR(realValue), ADR(LSW), 2);
```

I would assume Schneider has a similar command.

Comment: For the moment, I have assigned these two words to adjacent memory locations (%MW0, %MW1) and then defined a REAL variable at %MD0.
I will try the above, as in some cases I want to keep to 'symbolic' addressing, rather than 'immediate' addressing.